Does migrating a PC to another domain cause GPO related registry keys from previous domain to be reset/removed?
I have a pc that is joined to the active directory domain and has group policy objects applied as expected. Multiple group policy objects and multiple policies are in effect on this pc including some "Extra Registry Settings".
Now, I am migrating this pc to another domain which has its own group policy objects and policies that are different from the current domain. So for example, the current domain has a policy in "Extra Registry Settings" which is applied on the said pc, but the new domain doesn't have any extra registry settings. Same e.g. for NTP settings pushed by GPO. Current domain enforces an NTP server for time sync, the new one doesn't.
My question is this: when I migrate this pc from the current domain to the new domain, is there a chance that some of the registry keys related to Group Policies of the current domain will not be removed/reset and will cause inconsistency between new policies the new domain is supposed to apply and what is actually applied on this pc after migration?

The answer is the same as having multiple GPO objects, and assign them to security groups, then change the security groups for a user so they get a different GPO affected. Except, if you use the preferred way to switch domains, then it doesn't apply (see last paragraph).
It basically comes down to this:
In the GPO, you have 3 main settings: Enabled, Disabled, Do not change.
A GPO can have a persistent setting or a cached setting. A cached setting basically sets a registry key and keeps updating it on every refresh. You can spot a leaf icon in the GPO settings if this is the case. A persistent setting is set everytime the GPO is applied.
If your applied GPO settings change, for example, you removed a setting from the GPO or you got swapped to a different GPO due to a different security group or as in this question, a different domain with different GPO, then it is going to change the persistent settings, but if a cached setting was set, and at the new location it wasn't, then the setting is carried over and remains in effect.
Now, lastly, there is one more thing at play here.
Given you mention you are going to move from domain to domain, if you choose to migrate the domain user to a local user, and then migrate the local user back to the new domain, you will carry over these left overs.
If you choose to just leave the current domain, and join the new domain, the user will automatically get a new profile and there are no leftover GPO settings.
